# Meta-analysis using metafor package in R: back-transforming for funnel plot X-axis

Tags: r, data-visualization

I am using the `metafor` package in R to conduct a meta-analysis, and the `funnel()` function for creating a standard funnel plot.

My effect sizes are correlations and I am transforming them to Z-scores, via the `measure="ZCOR"` argument in `rma()`, for combining, then back-transforming for reporting.

I am interested in presenting the raw correlations in the funnel plot.  I'm pretty sure I need to use the `atransf=` argument from `funnel()` to do this, but I can't find the appropriate back-transformation that will give raw rather than transformed correlations.

I saw my exact question on the R-help archives a while back and unfortunately am having trouble finding it again; the GMane archives appear to be not working, at least for me. Apologies if this answer is easily found somewhere online; I've searched the JSS `metafor` article, package documentation and package website with no luck so far.  I guess a related question would be: is there a master list somewhere of all of the possible values of the `transf` and `atransf` arguments?

Here is example code that produces the funnel plot WITH transformed values on the X-axis.  I am looking for display of the untransformed values.

```
library(metafor)
mydat <- data.frame(raw_corrs = c(.22,.35,.01,-.05,.16), 
    N =c(50,70,90,130,20))
model1 <- rma(ri=raw_corrs, ni=N, data=mydat, measure="ZCOR")
funnel(model1)
```

Comment: Apologies for missing this---reproducible example added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package documentation for `metafor` gives a list of useful transformation functions under the `transf` topic. Note that the `transf` and `atransf` arguments will in fact accept any valid function.

In your case, you are using Fisher's r-to-z transformation for correlations, and so the appropriate back-transformation can be achieved by setting `atransf = transf.ztor`

Comment: Oh man, I can't believe I missed that in the package documentation.  Many thanks for the assist.

Comment: Things like this are good to know. I just improved the documentation with links to the help page for all those transformation functions for any function that has a ``transf`` and/or ``atransf`` argument. This is now already in the 'devel' version (http://www.metafor-project.org/doku.php/installation#development_version).

Comment: Thank you @Wolfgang, and many thanks for all of your work creating and maintaining `metafor`!